# Les graphies obsolètes sont-elles encore « correctes » ?

Tags: orthographe, ancien-français

C'est une question un peu bizarre, mais bon.

Il faut savoir qu'anciennement, *savoir* et *préférer* s'écrivaient respectivement *sçavoir* [(source)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%C3%A7avoir) et *praeferer* [(source)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A6ferer). Depuis, ces graphies sont devenues obsolètes et inutilisées. Cependant, est-ce qu'on pourrait théoriquement encore les utiliser sans que ce soit une faute ? C'est sûr que ce n'est pas une bonne idée dans la vie courante ou dans un examen, mais théoriquement ?

Comment: Tout est dans ce *théoriquement*. Il n'y a pas de correction "objective" ou absolue, seulement des usages adaptés ou non à tel ou tel contexte. En dehors de l'énumération des contextes dans lesquels cet emploi est envisageable, j'ai peur que tu ne trouves pas de réponse définitive et universelle...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non, elles ne le sont plus. C'est considéré comme de l'ancien français.
Écrire « sçavoir » au lieu de « savoir » sera invariablement considéré comme une faute au milieu d'un texte de français moderne.

L'ancien français et le français moderne sont tellement éloignés, pas seulement dans la graphie, mais surtout dans la prononciation, la grammaire, et la manière d'utiliser les mots, avec des mots qui n'ont plus du tout le même sens en français moderne, que c'est la même langue, sans être la même langue. Il faut un certain entraînement et avoir un bon dictionnaire sous la main pour comprendre un texte d'ancien français.

Comment: Merci. Donc, je suppose que l'usage actuel est instauré depuis tellement longtemps que l'ancien usage est considéré comme du moyen/ancien français. Est-ce exact?

Comment: @Archa En effet. Les langues évoluent, et les graphies médiévales n'ont plus court aujourd'hui. Il existe toutefois certaines graphies qui sont normalement obsolètes mais sont encore acceptées : celles qui ont été modifiées suite à la réforme de 1990. Certains puristes reprocheront l'usage d'une ancienne graphie, d'autre la volonté simplificatrice qui abîme notre langue, mais au final l'usage de l'une ou l'autre est rarement considéré comme une faute.

Answer (score 5):

> *Le vieux langage ne doit pas être du tout méprisé par celui que nous
>   avons mais il lui est comme serait à un riche homme outre tous ses
>   autres biens un grand château qui aurait été de ses ancêtres et auquel
>   trouvant quelques beau membres encore que le bâtiment fût à la façon
>   ancienne il ne le voudrait laisser du tout déshabité.*
>
> [ H. Étienne, [*Projet du livre de la Précellence du langage français*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qm9iVbvXFCYC&vq=chasteau&dq=Projet%20du%20livre%20de%20la%20Pr%C3%A9cellence%20du%20langage%20fran%C3%A7ais&pg=PA191#v=onepage&q&f=false), 1579 ]

C'est ce qu'on trouve sur la page couverture des *Oeuvres choisies d'Étienne Pasquier* (voir [autre contexte](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14156)). L'intérêt réside dans le fait que dans l'article *Wikipédia* sur les *rectifications orthographiques*, on aborde directement le cas de la forme *sçavoir* en référant à cet auteur<sup>1</sup>:

> On trouve d'autres exemples qui montrent les limites d'une orthographe
>   étymologique. Ainsi, *sçavoir* (saver en ancien français) était censé
>   se rattacher au latin *scire* jusqu'à ce qu'on s'aperçoive qu'il était
>   issu du bas-latin *sapere* (cf. italien *sapere*) et qu'on enlève,
>   tardivement, le ç parasite.<sup>[note ref. Pasquier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais#cite_note-8)</sup>
>
> [ Wikipedia, [*Rectifications orthographiques du français*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais) ]

Ceci est confirmé au [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/savoir), où on indique que c'est vraiment au 15e et au 16e qu'on introduit le *ç*. La [version française](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/savoir) du *Wiktionnaire* va plus loin que la version anglaise produite en question, qui se contente de parler d'*hypercorrection*. C'était une erreur que de rattacher le verbe à *scire* qui n'est pas représenté en français, sauf dans *science* et dans les mots avec un suffixe -*scient*. Le latin vulgaire *sapere* est lui-même une altération du classique *sapere*, dans le sens premier de *sentir avec le goût*. On mentionne qu'il faudra [attendre](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=s%C3%A7avoir) l'Académie 3<sup>e</sup> (1740) pour qu'on se débarasse du *ç*. Cette forme [apparaît](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXdXcfXsb;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s022d0338;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;) donc en [moyen français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyen_fran%C3%A7ais) et ne constitue pas la forme [première](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/saveir1) (*saveir*, 980, Rey/*DHLF*) en ancien français. En résumé *sçavoir* était déjà une erreur même quand la graphie était usuelle, donc a fortiori aujourd'hui.

Enfin on peut reviser la [mission](http://academie-francaise.fr/linstitution/les-missions) initiale de l'*Académie française* et son rôle prescriptif, d'un équilibre difficile, dans l'[histoire](http://academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/le-francais-aujourdhui) de la langue d'une nation. Ici on a noté que depuis 1740 on n'admet plus cette graphie; et aucune source courante ne l'admet. Évidemment, toute personne est libre d'écrire exactement ce qu'elle veut ou de situer son discours dans un contexte historique particulier de la langue.

---

<sub>1. J'ai retracé les documents dont on fait état dans Wikipedia; *Pasquier* s'y prononcera sans doute dans le sens d'une interprétation du latin vulgaire qui vise a en faire ressortir l'origine classique. Voir 1- [Recherches, III, l : De l'origine de nostre vulgaire François, que les Anciens appelaient Roman, et dont procede la différence de l'orthographe et du parler](https://books.google.com/books?id=_mq32lkn2pMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=pasquier%20oeuvres&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aBiHVYmLMMGnyATA7LGYBw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) et 2- [Lettres, III, iv : Sçavoir si l'orthographe françoise se doit accorder avec le parler](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cf55J54Qy8oC&dq=%22accorder%20avec%20le%20parler%22%20pasquier&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q&f=false). *Wikipédia* le tient-il pour responsable ou y réfère-t-on pour fins d'illustrations; allez savoir!</sub>