# What is the history of the spelling of "dromadaire"?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, phonétique, grec

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the English word *dromedary* derives from the Old French *dromedaire* and Latin *dromedarius* — which, like the English word, have an *e* in the second syllable. However, the Latin word ultimately derives from Greek *δρομας* (*dromas*) meaning "running", with an *a* in the second syllable.

Having just started learning [these songs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfcOUCjdHJY), I'm now painfully aware that in modern French, the word is *le dromadaire*, which, like the ancient Greek root, is spelled with an *a*.

1. When did this change occur?
2. Is it the result of some kind of attempt to reconcile spelling with etymology, or is there some other reason for it? (i.e., is it more than a coincidence that the modern French spelling matches the ancient Greek?)

Comment: To my knowledge, the evolution is more often to reconcile the spelling with the _pronunciation_. I don't know for this particular case, however.

Answer (score 6):

Vowels are prone to change and this word is not an exception but one example among many.

The Old French word *dromedere* derived form Vulgar Latin *dromedarius* but it was already *dromadaire* in [Middle French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_French) (14th century). The shift in pronunciation occurred sometime during the [Old French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_French) period. The pronunciation of lots of vowels changed during that period, the opposition short/long vowels became an opposition open/closed vowels and consequently lots of closed vowels became open or *vice versa* (so [ə] shifted to [a]).
By the time French spelling was fixed the word was most likely pronounced with an [a] sound.

To be noted that Greek  *δρομας* (*dromas*) gave classical Latin [*drom**a**s*](http://www.dicolatin.fr/FR/LAK/0/DROMADIS/index.htm). So the *a* was already present in Classical Latin. A shift from *a* to *e* occurred from Classical Latin to Vulgar Latin.

Answer (score 3):

Now that it's clear from [another answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14155) that you had both forms from very early on<sup>1</sup>, and that it was most likely pronounced like it is today after the described *shift*, there is still the issue of what happens afterwards, which is relevant to your second question, and which ultimately leads to the topic of *orthographic reforms*:

> L'adoption du français comme langue royale, en remplacement du latin,
>   a déclenché chez les clercs une réaction qui s'est traduite par la
>   mise en place d'une orthographe raisonnée du moyen français se
>   référant aux origines latines de la langue.
>
> [...]
>
> L'adoption du français comme langue royale se traduit par une
>   rationalisation et une unification de l'orthographe jusqu'ici
>   chaotique de l'ancien français (pour *cœur* par exemple on trouve les
>   graphies *quors*, *cuer* et *quers*). Alors que la graphie originelle du
>   français est davantage conforme à la phonétique (celle de l'époque) et
>   parfois arbitraire, elle est progressivement latinisée dans une
>   tentative pour aboutir à une « orthographe étymologique ». L’Académie
>   française fige ensuite définitivement cette nouvelle norme graphique
>   qu’elle appelle « orthographe ancienne » puisque procédant du [latin
>   classique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_classique), sans tenir compte du fait que la [Chanson de Roland](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanson_de_Roland), 
>   qui est
>   le plus vieux texte littéraire complet du français, a une orthographe
>   totalement différente[...] L'immense majorité des singularités
>   orthographiques du français moderne est étymologiquement justifiée et
>   se rapproche partiellement du latin classique à l'origine du [latin
>   vulgaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_vulgaire) dont descend le français. On trouve d'autres exemples qui
>   montrent les limites d'une orthographe étymologique.[...]
>
> Lorsque François Ier va promulguer sa célèbre ordonnance de
>   [Villers-Cotterêts](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordonnance_de_Villers-Cotter%C3%AAts) en août 1539, c'est l'usage du « françoys » qu'il
>   impose. L'invention de l'imprimerie, instrument de popularisation de
>   l'écrit, ne contribuera pas non plus à restituer à la langue française
>   sa graphie phonétique originelle dans la mesure où l'apparition de
>   cette technologie nouvelle a, au contraire, suscité des inquiétudes
>   concernant les éventuels « dangers » d'une dissémination incontrôlée
>   du français à l'écrit, d'où la nécessité ressentie de la compliquer un
>   peu plus encore par le recours non seulement au latin, mais également
>   au grec[...]
>
> [ Wikipedia, [*Rectifications orthographiques du français*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais) ]

Follows a reference to [*Henri Estienne*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Estienne) (1528-1598), and his *hellenizing* [stance](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50592v/f258.item.r=bigarr%C3%A9.zoom), common back then, the echoes of which you can hear up to this day, such as when he says:

> [...]mais pour l'esgard des etymologies des mots françois tirées du grec, je
>   ne veulx point aussi oublier de protester que mon intention n'est
>   aucunement de parler du françois de la 'maigre orthographe'[...]
>
> [ *Conformité du langage françois avec le grec*., Henri Estienne, 1569
>   ]

This refers to efforts by some, such as [*Louis Meigret*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Meigret), who introduced the first French grammar in 1550, to simplify the spelling along the lines of pronunciation; this was strongly rejected at that time, as [discussed](https://books.google.com/books?id=jMOCBtYzkqAC&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false) in [*Etienne Pasquier*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tienne_Pasquier_%28po%C3%A8te%29)'s (1529-1615) work, to which an editor's note in *Estienne*'s refers:

> Tous lesquels ores qu'ils conspirassent à même point d'orthographe et
>   qu'ils tinssent pour proposition infaillible qu'il fallait écrire
>   comme on prononçait si est-ce que chacun d'eux usa de diverses
>   orthographes montrant qu'en leur règle générale il n'y avait rien si
>   certain que l'incertain et de fait leurs orthographes étaient si
>   bizarres ou pour mieux dire si bigarrées qu'il était plus malaisé de
>   lire leurs œuvres que le grec.
>
> [ *Oeuvres choisies d'Etienne Pasquier*, Léon Feugère, 1849, t.2, p.20 ]

There is also reference to a sharp [refutation](https://archive.org/stream/mlangestirsd00nodi#page/386/mode/2up) by [*Charles Nodier*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Nodier) (1780-1844):

> Qu'est-ce que votre *fisike* ? Un science étroite et sèche. La
>   *physique* dérive du souffle qui anime le monde.[...]
>
> Il n'y a pas un seul vocable étymologiquement orthographié qui ne
>   fasse naître dans l'esprit l'idée très nette d'un fait littéraire,
>   d'un fait historique, d'un fait moral; si vous lui enlevez cette
>   valeur implicite, cette condition virtuelle du sens, vous avez tué
>   l'âme de la parole, l'*esprit* qui anime le *verbe* : il ne vous reste
>   qu'un cadavre.
>
> [ *Mélanges tirés d'une petite bibliothèque : ou Variétés littéraires
>   et philosophiques*, Charles Nodier, 1829, p. 386, [395 et ss](https://archive.org/stream/mlangestirsd00nodi#page/394/mode/2up).]

This was the tone and the influence which prevailed for quite some time from [classical](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise#Du_XVIe_au_XVIIIe.C2.A0si.C3.A8cle_:_fran.C3.A7ais_classique) to modern French; etymology as a touchstone, followed with some successive and continuing [evolution](http://archives.lesoir.be/le-jour-ou-orthographe-s-8217-ecrira-ortografe_t-20090316-00M5VN.html) of the spelling ("*L’écriture est la peinture de la voix: plus elle est ressemblante, meilleure elle est.*", Voltaire, *Dictionnaire philosophique*, "Orthographe", 1764), sometimes in the "wrong" [direction](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9forme_de_l%27orthographe_fran%C3%A7aise_de_1835). That doesn't mean that "*dromadaire*" ended up spelled like this because of such reactions, as we've seen that both forms existed earlier on; but it does provide the setup at the time whereby etymology played a central role generally; and the contemporary form of "dromadaire" happens to be in line with its etymology, as we all know now.

---

<sub>1. The first use of the word is attributed to [*Philippe de Thaon*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_de_Thaon) in the [*Bestiary*](http://bestiary.ca/etexts/wright1841/wright1841.htm) (1121): "*dromedaire*" is used therein (about an *ant*: *Il porte de sun grant de plum sum fais pesant, Içeo ne pot nent faire cheval ne dromedaire*.). But as always the [*DmF*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXgXrmXdjhf;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s060d3038;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;) and [*Godefroy*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/dromadaire) show the variety of the forms so you could still find "*dromedaire*" in the late 15th. But when the 1st edition of the *Dictionnaire de l'Académie* appears (1694), it refers to "[dromadaire](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=dromadaire)".</sub>

Comment: Bel effort documentaire ! :)

Comment: Une phrase qui m'avait échappé : "La physique dérive du souffle qui anime le monde.[...]", en orient cela s'appelle la *Réalité* paraît-il... et ce serait l'origine de tous les souffles qui naissent et se résorbent, celui de la respiration comme ceux des énergies connues et mal ou inconnues.