# Les mots qui ont subi le même sort que l'« abîme » (révision graphique du y vers i à l'encontre de l'étymologie) ?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, histoire

« Le nom *abyme* [Du latin chrétien [*abyssus*]](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/ab%C3%AEme) ne prend un *y* que dans la locution *en abyme*, autrement il s'écrit *abîme* » ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8357142)). On doit la locution « mettre en abyme » à [André Gide](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Gide) dans son [*Journal*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.187057/page/n35) de 1893 et la locution « mise en abyme » apparaît formellement en 1950 grace à [Claude-Edmonde Magny](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude-Edmonde_Magny) dans son *Histoire du roman français depuis 1918* ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_abyme#Origine_de_l'expression)). Au TLFi on a des explications d'une richesse inouïe pour le mot [abîme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ab%C3%AEme), dont celles-ci  (voir aussi *Le Bon Usage*, §96(a)1º où l'on apprend entre autres que le y de *may* et *roy* n'est remplacé par i par l'Académie qu'en 1740) :

> Graphie *y* et *i*. Dès l'entrée du mot dans la langue, la graphie
>   étymologique avec *y* est concurrencée par des formes en *i* en raison
>   de la confusion qui régnait entre ces graphies. En effet, dès le
>   xiies., *y* était introduit par les copistes à la place de l'*i* dans
>   les noms propres et dans les mots de physionomie étrangère (*cf.*
>   Beaul. t. 1 1927, p. 51). A partir du xiiies., l'*y* fut utilisé comme
>   « litera legibilior » à la place de *i* voyelle. « A la fin du xiiie
>   s. l'abus de l'*y* à toutes les places du mot était fort répandu, et
>   dans les régions les plus diverses de la langue d'oïl. » (Beaul. t. 1,
>   pp. 163-165). Cet abus n'a cessé de s'accentuer (*cf.* Beaul. t. 1,
>   pp. 271-276). Ronsard recommande le remplacement de l'*y* grec dans
>   *abisme, cigne, Nimphe*, etc., par « l'*i* françois pour monstrer qu'ils sont nostres, et non plus incogneus estrangers; ... » (Opinions
>   de Ronsard sur l'orthographe étymologique en tête de l'*Abrégé de
>   l'Art poétique* ds Didot 1868, p. 122). Rich. 1680 supprime l'*y* dans
>   *abîme*, mais Fur. 1690, Ac. 1694 à 1762, le maintiennent ainsi que *Trév.* 1752 et 1771. Ce n'est qu'à partir de *Ac.* 1798 que *i* l'emporte définitivement et [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/ab%C3%AEme) note encore : « On n'écrit plus
>   *abyme*, malgré l'étymologie ». (Pour la suppression et le
>   rétablissement de l'*y* grec dans les différentes éd. d'*Ac.*, cf.
>   Didot, p. 85).
>
> [ *Trésor informatisé de la langue française* (TLFi), *abîme* (section
>   prononciation et orthographe) ]

Est-on capable de donner un ordre de grandeur du nombre de mots contenant un *i* plutôt qu'un *y* qui ont été soit « nationalisés » (désignant ce que Ronsard explique) ou orthographiés « erronément » (par confusion), **contrairement à leur graphie étymologique** ?

De ce nombre, sait-on quelle proportion aurait fait l'objet d'un rajustement orthographique compatible avec l'étymologie et qui constitue l'orthographe courante du mot, comme avec la locution *(mise) en abyme* ?

Incidemment, par curiosité, est-on capable de produire le passage exact de l'ouvrage *Histoire du roman français depuis 1918* qui contient la locution « mise en abyme » si la locution apparaît ailleurs qu'uniquement dans l'intitulé du chapitre « La "mise en abyme" ou le chiffre de la transcendance. » ?

Comment: @Survenant9r7.A une époque ( je pense vers le 16e-17e s.) , d'après ce que m'a raconté un professeur de lettres classiques, les lettrés ont voulu " corriger" la graphie de " savoir" en " sçavoir" en raison d'une fausse étymologie qui prétendait relier  ce mot au latin " scire" . La véritable étymologie est " sapere" : "savoir" est de la même famille que "savourer", "saveur" et "sagesse" ( sapientia en latin).

Comment: @RayLittleRock Merci, oui c'est vrai, j'ai déjà lu un [contenu](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14158/19187) sur ce sujet.

Answer (score 3):

Le français, comme de nombreuses langues du vieux continent, est tres ancien. La langue évolue au fur-et-à-mesure et ce depuis des centaines d'années. Je doute qu'il existe des listes précises quant à ce recensement qui me paraît être un travail titanesque. Entreprendre cette tâche pourrait néanmoins être intéressant, par amour de la langue et de l'étymologie. Il est plus simple par exemple de retrouver des corrections telles que "abîme" -> "abime", suite aux rectifications orthographiques de 1990. Ces rectifications sont en effet documentées, par l'Académie Française notamment.

A noter que l'on retrouve des changements similaires comme "scenario" (latin) devant s'écrire "scénario" en français et son pluriel "scénarios" et non scenarii qui est le pluriel latin et non admissible en français selon l'Académie.

Je ne suis pas certain de bien répondre mais comme je l'ai dit précédemment, il me semble peu probable que de tels chiffres existent, car cela concerne des evolutions disparates. Cependant, si ces chiffres existent, c'est sans aucun doute auprès des archives de l'Académie qu'il faut s'adresser.

Comment: Bonjour. D'après ce que vous me dites là, il me semble donc que vous ayez la réponse à votre question. Dans ces cas-là, je ne peux pas mieux répondre et je suis désolé pour mon manque de précisions; je souhaitais simplement participer à la discussion car cela m'intéresse aussi et je souhaitais ajouter ces 2 points.

Comment: Merci de la contribution. Non je n'ai pas la réponse. La participation et la réponse sont les bienvenues.